# opening offline tiles in Osmdroid

Tags: java, android

i am trying to develop an offline map using osmdroid and trying to use the mbtiles created from mobile atlas creator but every-time i open the application it crashes. here is my main activity code. When i use the normal jpg file to load tiles, it works fine but its no use as i cannot bound the maps.

```
    package com.maptry.katgp;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
    import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
    import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
    import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.IRegisterReceiver;
    import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource;
    import org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBoxE6;
    import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
    import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
    import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
    import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.app.Activity;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IRegisterReceiver {
// initializing the mapview
MapView mapView;
// private MapController mapController;
 // ArrayList<OverlayItem> anotherOverlayItemArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // contents from the main

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // connecting with the xml layout id

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    // setting the default online tiles
    // mapnik not working so replaced by mapquest

    // for online use
    // mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);

    //adding the offline tiles using mbtiles

     DefaultResourceProxyImpl resProxy;
        resProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(this.getApplicationContext());



        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "maptile.mbtiles");

        MBTileProvider provider = new MBTileProvider(this, file);
        BoundedMapView mapView = new BoundedMapView(this, resProxy, provider);

        double north = 27.749177;
        double east  =  85.382652;
        double south = 27.648864;
        double west  =  85.262489;
        BoundingBoxE6 bBox = new BoundingBoxE6(north, east, south, west);

        mapView.setScrollableAreaLimit(bBox);

    /*
     * // adding the offline tiles
     * 
     * mapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapQuest",
     * ResourceProxy.string.mapquest_osm, 13, 18, 256, ".jpg", new String[]
     * { "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
     * "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
     * "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/",
     * "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/" }));
     */

    // for zooming and multitouch controls

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
     MapController controller = mapView.getController();
        controller.setZoom(12);
        controller.animateTo(new GeoPoint(27.7, 85.32));
}
```

}

Comment: I'm using Osmdroid ZIP for the offline tiles and it's working fine, try it out, if you really need full details of it, i'll show it how to create the zip tiles + use them in your app

Comment: yes zip files works perfectly for me too but I'm having problem of bounding my map i.e show only particular area and get rid of other empty blocks.